# 0x3f500000000 tag in /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats

Tags: android, proc

I use TrafficStats.setThreadStatsTag(0xf00d) to set a tag in my thread which is used to fetch images from internet.

However, I found there is another tag 0x3f500000000 when I cat the /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats file. The 0x3f500000000  tag and 0xf00d tag are both under the same uid.

```
 20 wlan0 0x3f500000000 10070 0 1849708 1237 63272 1040 1849708 1237 0 0 0 0 63272 1040 0 0 0 0

21 wlan0 0x3f500000000 10070 1 2877391 1924 79863 1440 2877391 1924 0 0 0 0 79863 1440 0 0 0 0

22 wlan0 0xf00d00000000 10070 0 16500 11 684 11 16500 11 0 0 0 0 684 11 0 0 0 0

23 wlan0 0xf00d00000000 10070 1 52012 39 3326 47 52012 39 0 0 0 0 3326 47 0 0 0 0
```

Dose anybody know who set the 0x3f500000000 tag?

What is the exact meaning of the network statistics under this tag ?

Answer (score 0):

10070 this app set the tag for itself. this tag means it's tag 0's child, tag 0's data is total, and tag0x3f500000000 stand for one socket in 10070 application, and then tag0xf00d000000 is an other socket in 10070 application, they are all belong to 10070, and also have been included in tag 0.

Answer (score 0):

If the UID is 10070, the tag 0x3f5 => 1013 is likely to be Media Services, indicating the app is using the system service.